# How to run javascript code from php (re-show hidden field after submit)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm making a registration form where you can write a custom security question. If this one is selected, when an error occurs (e.g wrong pass) it should reshow the field. But it does not do that.

This is the field:

```html
<div id="ifYes" style="display: none">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Custom security question"
      name="SEC1Q"
      onchange="DefaultCheck(this);"
    />
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <div class="input-group-text">
        <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how the field gets shown:

```
<select class="form-control <?php if($q1Empty == true) echo 'is-invalid'; ?>" onchange="QuestionCheck1(this);" name="Q1">
```

```js
function QuestionCheck1(that) {
  if (that.value == "other") {
    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
  }
  $(that).removeClass("form-control is-invalid");
  $(that).addClass("form-control");
}
```

I've tried this:

```
<?php
  echo "prepq1();";
?>
unction prepq1() {
  document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: there is plenty subjects on ajax here.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Comment: I'm confused what the PHP has to do with this, because the functions you've shown are all in JS.

Comment: I have no idea why mister jojo suggests to use ajax with PHP either. And the reason this has to do with PHP is that the function should only be called inside a certain IF statement. And none of these examples show me how I would show the field if a php variable is a certain value.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea why people said this has nothing to do with php or that ajax or a form should be used in this matter while a form is already used?

This was my solution may anyone bump into this with a similar issue:

```
<?php
    if($q1 == "other") $style = "display: block;"; // if question 1 is custom
    else $style = "display: none;";
?>
<div id="ifYes" style="<?php echo $style; ?>">
```